# Win32 Run-time Check Failure#2 Stack around the variable 'buffer' was corrupted

Tags: c++

Есть две потоковые функции, одна читает из файла и записывает в N-е количество копий.
Второй поток вычитывает все копии в один файл.

Почему после завершения работы программы появляется ошибка повреждения статического массива *char*?

> Stack around the variable 'buffer' was corrupted

```
DWORD WINAPI Write_Files(LPVOID lp)
{
    srand(time(0));
    random = rand() % 6 + 1;
    TCHAR str[MAX_PATH];
    HWND hDialog = (HWND)lp;
    char buffer[4096];
    TCHAR t[10];

    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);

    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, Read_Files, 0, 0, NULL);
    CloseHandle(hThread);   

    for (int i = 0; i < random; i++)
    {
        ifstream in(TEXT("music.txt"), ios::binary | ios::in);
        if (!in)
        {
            MessageAboutError(GetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
        wsprintf(str, TEXT("copy_%d.txt"), i);
        ofstream out(str, ios::binary | ios::out | ios::trunc);
        while (!in.eof())
        {
            in.read(buffer, 4096);
            int n = in.gcount();
            out.write(buffer, n);
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }

    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
    wsprintf(t, L"Write  %d files", random);
    MessageBox(0, t, TEXT("Critical"), MB_OK);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: PS: Программа выполняет поставленную задачу, все копии создаются корректно.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`wsprintf(t, L"Write  %d files", random);` - Сколько минимум символов требуется для строки "`Write  %d files`" даже если `random` - ноль? 15. А места выделено под 9, вот и получаете повреждение памяти.